# Constructing result in operator vs operating on default-constructed object

Tags: c++, constructor, operators

I have a class which is essentially an array with labelled contents, and I'd like to define some operators for it.  I'd like to do it in such a way that changing the number of elements in the class is easy, as I expect future users will change the variables tracked, but I'd also like to ensure that basic arithmetic operations on the class are as efficient as possible.

I can see two way of implementing the operators.  Taking the example of a `Vector2D` class:

```
struct Vector2D {

    //members
      const static int nElem = 2;
      double x;
      double y;

    //Constructors
      Vector2D() {}          
      Vector2D(double X, double Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

    //Operators
      double& operator[] (int index) {
        switch(index) { 
          case 0:
            return x;
          case 1:
            return y;
          default:
            return std::out_of_range ("Oops");
        }
      }

    // Option 1: operator+ by constructing result
    Vector2D operator+ (const Vector2D & rhs) const {
      return Vector2D(x + rhs.x, y+rhs.y);
    }

    // Option 2: operator+ using loop and [] operator
    Vector2D operator+ (const Vector2D & rhs) const {
      Vector2D result;
      for(int i = 0; i < nElem; i++)
        result[i] = (*this)[i] + rhs[i];
      return result;
    }
};
```

Assuming I use -03 optimization, will there be any difference between the two implementations of `operator+`?  My understanding is that since the default `Vector2D` constructor has no code body and the class contents are a default data type, there is no extra overhead in Option 2 for calling the default constructor on `result` before setting its members.  I expect the two to be equivalent, but I'm not confident enough in my knowledge to be sure.

Comment: Your two implementations don't do the same thing... The second one just adds the `x` twice and, well, I'm not really sure how you wanted to do this

Comment: My mistake. Fixed option 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your method won't work at all. If you want someone to be able to change `nElem` you can't use `x`, `y` as your names. Why? Because changing `nElem` to 3 won't magically add `z`. And since you can't do a `for` loop over `x` and `y`, your definition of `nElem` is meaningless.

Finally, this is a textbook case for the use of a number template. Create a vector which is templated over how many elements it has.

Do something like this:

```
template<unsigned int LEN>
class Vector{
  double v[LEN];
public:
  Vector operator+(const Vector &o){
    Vector res;
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<LEN;++i) // with -O3 and small LEN this will be unrolled
      res.v[i]=v[i]+o.v[i];
  }
  // ... etc.
};
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Vector<2> my_2d_vec;
Vector<3> my_3d_vec;
```

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution for the vector example, but I don't think it's as appropriate for my case. My code handles a collection of variables which are often manipulated as a group, but are also occasionally handled individually. It's convenient to be able to modify them all as a group, but also to be able to refer to them each by a meaningful name (rather than an index).